# Can I call a superclass sort with a subclass compare in perl?

Tags: perl, subclass, superclass, subroutine

I want to use a superclass sort which uses a subclass compare function.  I've tried to distill the nature of the question in the following code.  This isn't the "production" code, but is presented here for illustration.  It's tested.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# $Id: foo,v 1.10 2019/02/23 14:14:33 bennett Exp bennett $

use strict;
use warnings;

package Fruit;
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless({}, $class);
    $self->{itemList} = [];
    warn "Called with class ", blessed $self, "\n";
    return $self;
}

package Apples;

use parent qw(-norequire Fruit);

sub mySort {
    my $self = shift;
    @{$self->{itemList}} = sort compare @{$self->{itemList}};
    return $self;
}

sub compare {
    $a->{mass} <=> $b->{mass};
}

package main;

my $apfel = Apples->new();
push(@{$apfel->{itemList}}, { "name" => "grannysmith", "mass" => 12 });
push(@{$apfel->{itemList}}, { "name" => "macintosh", "mass" => 6 });
push(@{$apfel->{itemList}}, { "name" => "Alkmene", "mass" => 8 });

$apfel->mySort();

for my $f (@{$apfel->{itemList}}) {
    printf("%s is %d\n", $f->{name}, $f->{mass});
}

exit 0;
```

What I want to do is to move `mySort()` to the abstract superclass `Fruit`.  I've tried a number ways of addressing the `$self->compare()` subroutine, but I'm not having much luck.

Any thoughts?

I've gotten it to call the correct subroutine, but never with the correct `$a` and `$b`.  I've left all of my failed attempts out of this question in the hopes that someone will know right away how to move the `mySort()` to the `Fruit` package so that I can sort my oranges with the same subroutine.

Comment: Well, I've certainly got a few things to check out with the answers below.  I'll get back to you all in a while.  All of the answers so far seem to be in the same vein.  @ikegami suggested that I might be trying to compare Apples to Oranges.  This will never be the case.  I just want to call the same `mySort()` on different subclasses, each with its own `compare()`.  The answers so far look promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two problems. First, you need the `mySort` function in the super class to call the `compare` function for the correct subclass. Second, you need the `compare` function in the subclass to be able to receive the two elements it wants to compare from a call in a different package.

It's not clear whether you worked out a solution to the first problem, but one solution is to use `UNIVERSAL::can` to find out the right comparison method.

```
package Fruit;
sub mySort {
    my $self = shift;
    my $compare_func = $self->can("compare");
    @{$self->{itemList}} = sort $compare_func @{$self->{itemList}};
}
```

This will find the correct subclass `compare` function and use it in the sort call.

Now the issue in the `Apples::compare` function will be that when `Fruit::mySort` is ready to compare a couple of elements, it will set the package variables `$Fruit::a` and `$Fruit::b`, not `$Apples::a` and `$Apples::b`. So your `Apples::compare` function must be prepared for this. Here are a couple of solutions:

```
package Apples;
sub compare {
    package Fruit;
    $a->{mass} <=> $b->{mass};
}
```

or

```
sub compare {
    $Fruit::a->{mass} <=> $Fruit::b->{mass}
}
```

or more defensively,

```
package Apples;
sub compare {
    my $pkg = caller;
    if ($pkg ne __PACKAGE__) {
        no strict 'refs';
        $a = ${"${pkg}::a"};
        $b = ${"${pkg}::b"};
    }
    $a->{mass} <=> $b->{mass}
}
```

---

**Update**: I thought about making a subroutine attribute that would copy `$a` and `$b` values into the correct package, but after benchmarking it and thinking about alternatives, I decided against it. Here were my results for posterity:

Consider three sort routines (that might be in another package and hard to use from the current package)

```
sub numsort { $a <=> $b }
sub lexsort { $a cmp $b }
sub objsort { $a->{value} <=> $b->{value} }
```

Here are some ways we can make these packages accessible:

1. implement a subroutine attribute to prepare the `$a` and `$b` variables in the right package. Implementation is too long to include here, but the sub declaration would look like

   ```
   sub numsort : CrossPkg { $a <=> $b }
   ```
2. rewrite the comparison function to compare `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` instead of `$a` and `$b`, and use a wrapper in the `sort` call

   ```
   sub lexcmp { $_[0] cmp $_[1] }
   ...
   @output = sort { lexcmp($a,$b) } @input
   ```
3. Perform the sort call in the correct package, so it sets the correct `$a` and `$b` values.

   ```
   @output = do { package OtherPackage; sort numsort @input };
   ```

And here are the benchmarking results. The `local` method is the ordinary `sort` call with no cross-package issues.

```
                 Rate attrib-numsort    wrap-numcmp  local-numsort repkg-numsort
attrib-numsort 1.17/s             --           -90%           -96%          -96%
wrap-numcmp    11.6/s           885%             --           -61%          -64%
local-numsort  29.5/s          2412%           155%             --           -8%
repkg-numsort  32.2/s          2639%           178%             9%            --

                 Rate attrib-lexsort  repkg-lexsort    wrap-lexcmp local-lexsort
attrib-lexsort 3.17/s             --           -12%           -14%          -17%
repkg-lexsort  3.60/s            13%             --            -2%           -5%
wrap-lexcmp    3.68/s            16%             2%             --           -3%
local-lexsort  3.80/s            20%             6%             3%            --

                 Rate attrib-objsort    wrap-objcmp  local-objsort repkg-objsort
attrib-objsort 1.22/s             --           -81%           -88%          -89%
wrap-objcmp    6.32/s           417%             --           -38%          -44%
local-objsort  10.1/s           730%            61%             --          -10%
repkg-objsort  11.3/s           824%            79%            11%            --
```

**Summary**: overhead is less of a concern with `lexsort`, 
where each comparison takes more time. The attribute 
approach is dead on arrival. Setting the package going into
the `sort` call has the
best results -- more or less no overhead -- but it isn't
suitable for this application (in an object hierarchy). 
Rewriting the comparison function and wrapping the function
in the `sort` call isn't too bad of a performance drop-off,
and it works in an object hierarchy, so the final
recommendation is:

```
package Fruit;
sub compare { ... }
sub mySort {
    my $self = shift;
    @{$self->{itemList}} =
        sort { $self->can("compare")->($a,$b) } @{$self->{itemList}};
}

package Apples;
our @ISA = qw(Fruit)
sub compare { $_[0]->{mass} <=> $_[1]->{mass} }
```

Comment: rules!  The `warn()`ings showed exactly what you would expect.  I'd post the text, but I don't know how to do preformatted in the comments.  It shows `new() called with class Apples` and `mySort() called with class Apples` and `compare() called with class Fruit`.  I used the "more defensively" `compare` and the `UNIVERSAL->can()`.

Answer (score 5):

The punctuation variables such as `$_`<sup>[1]</sup> are called "super-globals" because they refer to the variable in the `main::` namespace.<sup>[2]</sup> In other words, no matter what's the current package, `$_` is short for `$main::_`.

`$a` and `$b` aren't super-globals. They are ordinary package variables. `sort` populates the `$a` and `$b` of the package in which the `sort` is found, which leads to problems if `sort` and the compare function are found in different packages. This means that moving `mySort` to Fruit:: will cause `sort` to populate `$Fruit::a` and `$Fruit::b`, but your `compare` function reads `$Apple::a` and `$Apple::b`.

There are a few solutions you could use when multiple packages are involved, but the simplest is to use the `($$)` prototype on the compare function. This causes `sort` to pass the values to compare as arguments instead of using `$a` and `$b`.

```
package Foo;
my $compare = \&Bar::compare;
my @sorted = sort $compare @unsorted;

package Bar;
sub compare($$) { $_[0] cmp $_[1] }
```

`sort` calls the sub as a function, not a method. If you want it called as a method, you'll need a wrapper.

```
package Foo;
my @sorted = sort { Bar->compare($a, $b) } @unsorted;

package Bar;
sub compare { $_[1] cmp $_[2] }
```

That said, the idea of having `sort` in one class and the sorter in a sub class is fundamentally flawed. You can presumably have a list that contains both Apples and Oranges, so how can you determine which `compare` method to call?

```
package Foo;
my @sorted = sort { ???->compare($a, $b) } @unsorted;

package Bar;
sub compare { $_[1] cmp $_[2] }
```

---

1. And a few named ones too such as `STDIN`.
2. By using a fully-qualified name (e.g. `$package::_`), you can access the punctuation variables of other packages. These have no special meaning; they aren't used by Perl itself.

Comment: Contrary to what you've been told your whole life, [you can compare Apples and Oranges](https://www.improbable.com/airchives/paperair/volume1/v1i3/air-1-3-apples.php)

Comment: @mob, Jocularity aside, that kinda demonstrates my point. You can compare *fruits* by transmission spectra, by mass, etc, but you can't use a compare function that's specific to apples to compare fruits.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `$a` and `$b` are used by `sort` as package variables in the same package that sort was called, so in order for the child class to see them, you could try this.

In the parent class:

```
sub mySort {
    my $self = shift;
    @{$self->{itemList}} = sort { $self->compare($a, $b) } @{$self->{itemList}};
    return $self;
}
```

In the child class:

```
sub compare {
    my ( $self, $a, $b ) = @_;
    $a->{mass} <=> $b->{mass};
}
```