# Perl sort won't use function from another package

Tags: perl

I have a function for case insensitive sorting. It works if it's from the same package, but not otherwise.

This works:

```
my @arr = sort {lc $a cmp lc $b} @list;
```

This works (if a function called "isort" is defined in the same file):

```
my @arr = sort isort @list;
```

This does not (function exported with Exporter from another package):

```
my @arr = sort isort @list;
```

This does not (function referred to explicitly by package name):

```
my @arr = sort Utils::isort @list;
```

What is going on? How do I put a sorting function in another package?

Comment: See also [Can I call a superclass sort with a subclass compare in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54842607/2173773)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What evidence do you have for it not working? Have you put a `print()` statement in the subroutine to see if it's being called?

I suspect you're being tripped up by this (from [`perldoc -f sort`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)):

> `$a` and `$b` are set as package globals in the package the sort() is called from. That means `$main::a` and `$main::b` (or `$::a` and `$::b` ) in the `main` package, `$FooPack::a` and `$FooPack::b` in the `FooPack` package, etc.

Oh, and later on it's more specific:

> Sort subroutines written using `$a` and `$b` are bound to their calling package. It is possible, but of limited interest, to define them in a different package, since the subroutine must still refer to the calling package's `$a` and `$b`:
>
> ```
> package Foo;
> sub lexi { $Bar::a cmp $Bar::b }
> package Bar;
> ... sort Foo::lexi ...
> ```
>
> Use the prototyped versions (see above) for a more generic alternative.

The "prototyped versions" are described above like this:

> If the subroutine's prototype is `($$)` , the elements to be compared are passed by reference in `@_`, as for a normal subroutine. This is slower than unprototyped subroutines, where the elements to be compared are passed into the subroutine as the package global variables `$a` and `$b` (see example below).

So you could try rewriting your subroutine like this:

```
package Utils;

sub isort ($$) {
  my ($a, $b) = @_;

  # existing code...
}
```

And then calling it using one of your last two alternatives.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Pretty surprised I couldn't find this on the first page of Google or Stack Overflow results. I was all out of sorts.

Comment: @felwithe: For some reason, good Perl advice often doesn't rank well on Google. But you can always go directly to the [official documentation site](https://perldoc.perl.org/).